# Plaid connection returning Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: python, connection, plaid

What's strange is that this code works perfectly locally on localhost, but does not work on my site on PythonAnywhere.com.

My error log is showing:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args) File "/home/leehrat/BudgetApp/website/banking.py", line 182, in create_link_token response = client.link_token_create(request) File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 769, in __call__ return self.callable(self, *args, **kwargs) File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/api/plaid_api.py", line 10492, in __link_token_create return self.call_with_http_info(**kwargs) File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 831, in call_with_http_info return self.api_client.call_api( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 406, in call_api return self.__call_api(resource_path, method, File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 193, in __call_api response_data = self.request( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 452, in request return self.rest_client.POST(url, File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/rest.py", line 264, in POST return self.request("POST", url, File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plaid/rest.py", line 150, in request r = self.pool_manager.request( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request return self.request_encode_body( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw) File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw) File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen return self.urlopen( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen return self.urlopen( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen return self.urlopen( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen retries = retries.increment( File "/home/leehrat/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='production.plaid.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /link/token/create (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0245b24940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

What's weird after putting in a bunch of print() statements is the Plaid class "Products" and "CountryCodes" is returning back each letter of my lists rather than an expected value:

```
PLAID_PRODUCTS = 'auth,transactions'
products = []
print(f"PLAID_PRODUCTS: {PLAID_PRODUCTS}")
for product in PLAID_PRODUCTS:
    products.append(Products(product))
print(f"products: {products}")
```

Shows this in the server (output) log:

```
2023-07-26 19:22:08 PLAID_PRODUCTS: auth,transactions
2023-07-26 19:22:08 products: [a, u, t, h, ,, t, r, a, n, s, a, c, t, i, o, n, s]
```

When it should be:

```
PLAID_PRODUCTS: ['auth', 'transactions']
products: [auth, transactions]
```

(it's doing the same for Country Codes)

Not sure if this has anything to do with why the connection isn't being established when creating the link token. Here's that code (pulled directly from the quickstart project:

```
def create_link_token():

    try:
        request = LinkTokenCreateRequest(
            products=products,
            client_name="xxxx",
            country_codes=list(map(lambda x: CountryCode(x), PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES)),
            language='en',
            user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(
                client_user_id=current_user.get_id()
            )
        )
        if PLAID_REDIRECT_URI!=None:
            request['redirect_uri']=PLAID_REDIRECT_URI

        # create link token
        response = client.link_token_create(request)
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        print(f"LinkTokenCreateRequest just didn't work. {e}")
        return json.loads(e.body)
```

I tried hard coding values (rather than trying to call from env variables) and lots of print statements to see output, but I can't seem to get into the Products class of Plaid to debug that (although it's the same exact "do not touch" code Plaid comes with).

I also tried connecting to sandbox, development, and production with the same results (production is where I'm trying to connect).

I have the redirect URL setup in the Plaid Dashboard and SSL setup with PythonAnywhere.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two problems that I've figured out here.

1. Hard coding my PLAID_PRODUCTS = 'auth,transactions'. This should actually be a list like the original code PLAID_PRODUCTS = os.getenv('PLAID_PRODUCTS', 'transactions').split(',')
2. Pythonanywhere has issues with 'proxy' when using the free account. Although plaid is whitelisted, I went ahead and purchased a paid plan which takes away proxy requirements (I didn't want to mess with figuring out how to do that and continually debugging).